# Custom Notification is adding decimal points to a Salesforce field when posting in Slack

Tags: formula-field, decimal, slack, slack-salesforce-app, custom-notification

We have a notification built in Salesforce Notification Builder that is sent to a slack channel whenever an Opportunity is Closed. Part of the notification displays a number field from the Opportunity. This number field has "Decimal Places" set to 0 within Salesforce.

However, when the notification is posted in slack it adds a decimal value of ".0". Notification Builder doesn't support formulas like ROUND(), as it will just display it in plain text. Is this expected behavior? Why would Slack add a decimal point to a whole number?

[image: Field information]

[image: Notification Builder]

Slack Message:
[image: Slack Message]